# Can a business refuse to take credit cards?

Tags: credit-card, india, payment

A certain restaurant in Mumbai, one that is centrally located, does not accept credit cards. Can a business refuse to take credit cards?

Comment: There is no place to complain, as there is nothing illegal about it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  this appears to be aimed at singling out a place and not apt on this site

Comment: @Dheer I edited out the name of the restaurant because it was irrelevant. This is a good example of a question that is perhaps not very good, but it is on topic. A down vote is appropriate, if you like, but I think it should remain open, as it is on-topic. It already has a great answer.

Comment: I edited the question and voted to reopen.

Comment: It works for me.  It's a good question from a *consumer's* point of view.

Comment: A remarkable transmogrification from a rant about a restaurant and macroeconomic "what will happen to India?" to a general, new question, "must every business on the planet take credit cards?" If nothing else, we have one day left in 2016, and this was an appropriate occasion for me to use the word transmogrify in context. Once a year is fine, I just hate when It's cut so close.

Comment: Nice usage. I *did* add the India tag, so that should narrow it a little bit from *the planet*. I was mostly trying to accommodate Philipp's effort.

Comment: Nothing illegal about it. Businesses usually take only cash to avoid paying taxes on profits from sales receipts.

Answer (score 12):

Businesses are free to decide what payment methods they accept for their goods and services. Businesses sometimes advertise what credit cards they accept by posting some stickers at their door. When your credit card isn't among them and you don't have enough cash with you, ask about your card **before** you order.

If a business doesn't accept your credit card, your best recourse is to take your business elsewhere. When you already ate there and got into an awkward situation because you assumed that they would accept your card, you might also want to write an online review of the place and warn others to bring cash for their visit (but please be fair in the review. When the food and service are decent, a restaurant doesn't deserve a one star rating just because they don't take credit cards).

Note that businesses have good reasons to not accept credit cards. It often means additional cost for them in form of:

- buying the necessary devices for reading them
- training staff in credit card handling
- an additional processing fee for every credit card transaction
- additional bookkeeping and administrative overhead for dealing with the credit card company
- depending on local customs, it might affect the guest's tipping behavior negatively (where I am from, you usually tip in a restaurant by letting them keep the change. With credit cards there is no change, so tipping requires to actively tell the waiter how much to deduct, which is less convenient and might result in people forgetting to tip).

But there is also a more shady reason. Taking payment in cash means that there is no electronic trail of the transaction. That makes it far easier for an establishment to misreport their income. They might under-report it to evade taxes or over-report it to launder money (both are illegal, of course).

Comment: It is maybe worth noting that if a place of business does display the logo of a credit card company but does not accept their card, they may be violating the credit card's merchant agreement or misusing their trademarks, which is something you can report to the credit card company.

Comment: @BrenBarn Why would any business do that? A customer being unable to pay after they got served is far more of a problem for the business than for the customer.